# Extbase CommandController Task to delete the repo

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

i have my CommandController which i am using to define a scheduler task which cleans my repo out of data. For some reason this doesn't work. I am also not able to add() a new element to my $itemRepository (inside this commandcontroller). Any idea what i am missing??

```
<?php

namespace VENDX\Items\Command;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility;


class TestCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController
{
  /**
 * itemRepository
 *
 * @var \VENDX\Items\Domain\Repository\ItemRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $itemRepository;

/**
* @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager
* @inject
*/
protected $persistenceManager;

/**
*
* @return void
*/

public function repoDeleteCommand() {

    $this->$itemRepository->removeAll();

}


}

?>
```

Comment: Do you have your persistence set in BE context? Usually this can be easily done via `module.tx_yourext < plugin.tx_yourext`

Comment: well it looks different: i added `module.tx_items.persistence < plugin.tx_items.persistence` inside my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt and then included this static template on my root  - but it still doesn't work. If i try to removeAll() or just add($item) i keep getting: `Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /var/www/html/typo3conf/ext/items/Classes/Command/ImportCommandController.php on line 94`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i solved the issue:

in my first attempt i tried to use the repo through the above notation. But i missed that no '$' is need @ the repo as the namespace is already defined with $this.

wrong format:

```
public function repoDeleteCommand() {

    $this->$itemRepository->removeAll();

}
```

so the correct format is:

```
public function repoDeleteCommand() {

    $this->itemRepository->removeAll();

}
```